# display an image stored on my back server

Tags: vue.js, axios, symfony4

I have a **Docker** web application that uses a front container (**VueJS**) and a back container (**Symfony**).

I have a script in **VueJS** to upload an image, so this image is sent to the Symfony server and stored on it (by storing the path of the file on the mysql server in the same time).

I want to display this image on my **VueJS** container.

While trying to access the response URL, I have a

> 404 error.

Do you guys have an idea about this?

Comment: could please show us the code and to be clear you send the path of your vuejs container folder to mysql and retriove it?

Comment: You need to proxy image request on the backend container. In prod environment all api and image requests must be proxied with nginx.